# multiple select Laravel

Tags: laravel-4, model-binding, multiple-select

I am making a form with Laravel 4.2.  My select form field works, but my multiple-select form field isn't working.  I want to utilize Laravel's form model binding to update a record, but that fact that multiple select's submit and expect to receive an array and mySQL tables are "flat" is causing a problem.  Here is the code for my select:

1) View:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-1">
    {{ Form::label('yr_month', 'Month') }}
    {{ Form::select('yr_month', array('January'=>'January','February'=>'February','March'=>'March','April'=>'April','April'=>'April','June'=>'June','July'=>'July','August'=>'August','September'=>'September','October'=>'October','November'=>'November','December'=>'December'), $recurrence->yr_month, array('class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'yr_month', 'multiple'=>'false')) }}
</div>
```

2) Controller:

```
public function store()
{
    $recurrence = new Recurrence;
    $recurrence->yr_month = Input::get('yr_month');
    $recurrence->save();
}
```

3) Database.  mySQL table with a column named yr_month that stores the name of a single month.

How do I:

- store the array in the mySQL table given it just stores strings or ints in columns?
- get the values out of the table and into a form that will automatically re-populate the multi-select with form model binding if/when a user edits the values?

Comment: This will be for days of the month - a multi-select with 1-31.

Comment: try change your 'multiple'=>'true'

Comment: @sstarlight I know that will make the select input into a multi-select. The problem is how do you store the array in the mySQL table given it just stores strings or ints in columns, and how do you get the values out of the table and into a form that will automatically re-populate the multi-select with form model binding if/when a user edits the values.